# Chrome Tab Ordering?

Tags: google-chrome, browser

If I'm on the first tab, and I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, I want it to open next to (to the right of) the current tab. Is there an extension for this?

I think I want to change the closed tab ordering too... but I can never remember how I like it until I play with it. I think move to the left tab is what I like.

TabMixPlus gives me these options in FF, is there a similar extension available yet? Or some hidden options in Chrome?

Comment: The answer below the accepted one from jdunning works in 2022 on Ubuntu. https://superuser.com/a/1326712/388883

Answer (score 35):

Nathan's clever [how-to](https://superuser.com/a/1217114/736443) below on forcing a <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>tab</kbd> shortcut via devtools needs an update, since the extensions page code is now minified from Chrome 65 on. To simplify the process, I wrote a little snippet below that you can copy and paste into the console that lets you then just click a command to set its shortcut to <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>tab</kbd>.

1. Open `chrome://extensions/shortcuts` by pasting that into the location bar or going to the main menu > More Tools > Extensions, and then clicking the menu in the top-left to open Keyboard shortcuts.
2. Open the devtools console by pressing <kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>opt</kbd><kbd>J</kbd> on macOS or <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>J</kbd> on Windows/Linux.
3. Copy this code:

   ```javascript
   document.body.onclick = function(e) {
     gCT = !window.gCT;
     const p = e.composedPath(), cn = p[0].textContent,
       s = p.filter(p => p.className == "shortcut-card")[0],
       n = s?.children[0].children[1].textContent;
     if (n) chrome.management.getAll(es => {
       const ext = es.filter(e => e.name == n)[0], {id} = ext;
       chrome.developerPrivate.getExtensionInfo(id, i => {
         const c = i.commands.filter(c => c.description == cn)[0];
         if (c) chrome.developerPrivate.updateExtensionCommand({
           extensionId: id,
           commandName: c.name,
           keybinding: `Ctrl+${gCT ? "" : "Shift+"}Tab`
         });
       });
     });
   }
   ```
4. Paste it into the console next to the > and then press <kbd>enter</kbd>.
5. Go back to the shortcuts page and click the **label** of the command you want to set to <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>tab</kbd>, **not** the *Type a shortcut* field. As an example, for the [QuicKey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/quickey-%E2%80%93-the-quick-tab-s/ldlghkoiihaelfnggonhjnfiabmaficg) tab manager extension, the label is *Switch to previous tab*.

That's it! <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>tab</kbd> will appear as that command's shortcut as soon as you click it. If you want another command to get a <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>tab</kbd> shortcut, just click its label next. (The code will switch between these two shortcuts as you click.) These shortcuts will survive Chrome restarts, since it's the app itself writing to its preferences file.

---

If you want to use my [QuicKey extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/quickey-%E2%80%93-the-quick-tab-s/ldlghkoiihaelfnggonhjnfiabmaficg) to navigate tabs, there's a somewhat simpler process [outlined here](https://fwextensions.github.io/QuicKey/ctrl-tab/) that doesn't require clicking around in the keyboard shortcuts page.  The snippet of JS code used there is also more self-explanatory, in case you're wary of what the blob above is doing.

If you're on Windows, that page also outlines a way of getting something much closer to Firefox's <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>tab</kbd> menu, using an AutoHotkey script.

---

**2023-03-24:** Updated the code to work with Chrome 111+.

Comment: This is smart. I combined this solution with [Quick-tabs](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/quick-tabs/jnjfeinjfmenlddahdjdmgpbokiacbbb/related) as it enables moving backward AND forward between last used tabs

Comment: @Sharcoux, QuicKey also lets you move in both directions. It's just that it doesn't currently let you move from the current tab to the oldest used tab, to make it easy to get back to it without overshooting after you had gone back in the stack. I suppose if `ctrl-shift-tab` is the first press, I could let it start navigating in the forward direction.

Comment: Amazing! Spent hours on fighting with this, preference file was keeping on overriding... Now it all works, I can toggle my least tabs! thanks!

Comment: This is great.

I can't still get over it that they haven't just put in an option to use ctr-tab like any other app with sub-windows since 1993.

Comment: Absolutely cool. Now finally the hotkey is useful. For basic switches I can still use `CTRL+PGUP` and `CTRL+PGDN`

Comment: That saved me so much time, thank you so much!

Comment: works on Ubuntu! Just click the Name of the shortcut after saving the code. I use FLST extension does this one thing well (Focus Last Selected Tab).

Comment: In newer versions of Chrome you must use `e.composedPath()`

Comment: @NikolaMihajlović, thanks for the pointer! I've updated the code above to use that method.

Comment: Fine with v118.0.5993.118 (Build oficial) (64 bits)
TX a lot !!

Answer (score 15):

**Most-Recently-Used tab ordering in Chrome has finally become an option**, though it is undocumented, unsupported, hacky and complaints about the situation are ignored.

To get the desired behavior:

1. Install the [Ctrl-TAB MRU extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ctrl%20tab-mru/ialfjajikhdldpgcfglgndennidgkhik).  This extension provides MRU tab ordering that replaces the built-in tab switching mechanism.  You can bind it to any key you want, so long as the extension manager keyboard shortcut mapper can record it.  It can't record Ctrl-TAB or Ctrl-Shift-TAB.  Previously this meant suffering with sub-standard workarounds like binding to Ctrl-~.  But now there is a way, so:
2. To work around the lack of a non-recording way to set key combos, in the keyboard shortcut recorder set the bindings to the Ctrl+Tab MRU extension to something stupid like Ctrl-Shift-Q and Ctrl-Shift-X, to make it easy to search for.  Test out these shortcuts to see how the extension looks and behaves.
3. Close Chrome and use a text editor to open "%AppData%\local\google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Preferences" (%AppData% depends on your OS; in windows that's probably C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData)  This file contains all of your settings in JSON format, all crammed onto a single line.
4. Search for the two bindings you set earlier (Ctrl-Shift-Q and Ctrl-Shift-X) and edit them to Ctrl-Tab for next and Ctrl-Shift-Tab for previous.
5. Start Chrome, open three tabs and test switching between them with your new shortcuts.  If you don't see the behavior from step 2, go back to step 3 and try again.  For unknown reasons, Chrome occasionally ignores your Preferences file and then overwrites it (see below).

Caveats:

- **Every time you close Chrome, it will clobber your Preferences file** and reset your manually-created keybindings.  Also every time you edit an extensions settings or open Chrome or squint at Chrome funny.  You can mark the file ready-only (which might have negative side effects) or you can get used to editing your Preferences file frequently.  Or never close Chrome.  This is Chrome's fault for not thinking that keybinding is valid and removing it, even when it honors it.
- The Ctrl+Tab MRU extension won't trigger in a new tab until the tab has finished loading.  This is Chrome's fault.
- The Ctrl+Tab MRU extension has a clumsy workaround for using it on tabs that don't contain pages (blank tabs, settings tabs, etc) where it quickly creates a new tab, switches tabs and closes the new tab.  This is Chrome's fault.

Comment: Whilst I started trying the procedure in this answer with the best intent, I found myself disheartened at the prospect of having to re-edit the messy json file at every Chrome's whim. I then tried the extension "Autocontrol" as suggested by [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1630773/327009) and, oh my, that works wonders and some more!

Answer (score 15):

I've found a different way to change your keybindings for an extension to <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> that works with the [Ctrl-TAB MRU extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ctrl%20tab-mru/ialfjajikhdldpgcfglgndennidgkhik) that GDom posted. It syncs to your profile and doesn't reset when Chrome Sync syncs on load like editing the preferences does. I do it by using the debugger to manipulate the keybindings page.

I made a how-to on it: [How to bind an extension to Ctrl+Tab/Ctrl+Shift+Tab in Chrome and have it actually sync to your profile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zTvwI.jpg)

Comment: You are a freaking genius!

Comment: This is excellent. I noticed that the new Material UI version of the Extensions page has minified code now, so the steps are slightly different. But it inspired me to create a little snippet of JS you can run in devtools to set a `ctrl-tab` shortcut just by clicking the command, without having to set breakpoints and intercept the call. My answer is below: https://superuser.com/a/1326712/736443

Comment: Works still in 2021! Although step #4 should be skipped, and step #7 is "keybinding" instead of "keystroke". Or use the script from the now-above @jdunning answer. :)

Comment: Perfect. It still Worked (Chrome 92.0.4515.107) .  "keybinding" instead of "keystroke". Also worked with other extensions ( check on CLUT: Cycle Last Used Tabs)

Answer (score 5):

The [Autocontrol](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/autocontrol-shortcut-mana/lkaihdpfpifdlgoapbfocpmekbokmcfd) extension now allows to configure <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to switch tabs in the MRU order. Unlike the [CLUT](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/clut-cycle-last-used-tabs/cobieddmkhhnbeldhncnfcgcaccmehgn) and [Recent Tabs](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/recent-tabs/ocllfmhjhfmogablefmibmjcodggknml) extensions it resembles the Windows MRU windows switching with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>. See https://www.autocontrol.app/switch-to-last-used-tab-in-chrome for instructions.

Comment: Autocontrol doesn't work it switches between two windows only and not MRU list

Comment: @SoLaR, it works perfectly fine for me. I just followed the instructions in the link.

Comment: (MRU == Most Recent Used) I would say not - I've checked this second.

Comment: Oh my god this extension is fantastic!! Finally a proper Ctrl+Tab in Chrome! And how many other customisations! Absolutely recommended.

Comment: should be the top answer

Comment: No, I can't go back 2 or 3 tabs continuining to push ctrl tab...

Answer (score 3):

If you **right** click on a tab, and select "New tab", the new tab will open immediately to the right of the tab you clicked.

Give it a try.  There's more options there you might find useful.

Comment: Well, the whole point of this in the first place is convenience and speed. Having to right click kind of negates that. But good to know.

Answer (score 1):

FYI, I stumbled on the default Chrome Keyboard shortcut to switch between recent tabs, it is: Ctrl+1. For me this is easier than going though changing code in the debugger to get permanent ctrl+tab setting using the Ctrl-TAB MRU extension.

Edit: There is a Chrome extension that does this now in an alt-tab menu like fasion, called [Recent Tabs](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/recent-tabs/ocllfmhjhfmogablefmibmjcodggknml?hl=en). I still never remember ctrl+1!

Comment: ctrl+1 takes you to the 1st tab, ctrl+2 to the 2nd etc.. so not really switching back & forth

Answer (score 1):

Modified from the excellent [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1326712/388883) above for just Ctrl+Tab toggling.

- Go to `chrome://extensions/shortcuts`.
- Pressing cmd+opt+J or ctrlshiftJ.
- Paste the code and press enter.
- Click the name of the action under the name of the extension.

code:

```
document.body.onclick = function(e) {
    gCT = !window.gCT;
    var p = e.path, cn = p[0].textContent,
        s = p.filter(p => p.className == "shortcut-card")[0],
        n = s && s.children[0].children[1].textContent;
    n && chrome.management.getAll(es => {
        var ext = es.filter(e => e.name == n)[0], id = ext.id;
        chrome.developerPrivate.getExtensionInfo(id, i => {
            var c = i.commands.filter(c => c.description == cn)[0];
            chrome.developerPrivate.updateExtensionCommand({
                extensionId: id,
                commandName: c.name,
                keybinding: "Ctrl+" + "Tab"
            });
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: What's the difference? What is `window.gCT`?