# Chrome extension that makes Ctrl+Tab work like in Visual Studio

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

Does anyone here know if a Chrome extension exists, that will make Ctrl+Tab go to the last active tab - like in visual studio.

I know, I once found one for Firefox - which I can't find now - and wonder if something like that is available for Chrome.

Comment: It seems it's something that a lot of people needs http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=5569

Comment: Just what I need. More thumbnails to slow down my machine. . .

Comment: @surfasb: que??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to have a look at [Last Used Tab Switcher](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ocddljbpjlmffighalbidicfckecmfdg), it's as close as I can find but uses <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> instead of <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd>

Answer (score 6):

[AutoControl Shortcut Manager](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/autocontrol-shortcut-mana/lkaihdpfpifdlgoapbfocpmekbokmcfd) lets you remap <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> and any other shortcut really.

You can use it for switching tabs in MRU order, open order, normal order, across all windows, only the current window, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I now found a possiblity to achieve this for users working on Windows and wrote an extension: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ctrl%2Btab-mru/ialfjajikhdldpgcfglgndennidgkhik

Comment: This is indeed possible on windows using Daniel's extension (or possibly others using the same manual-editing technique).  Explained in more detail here: http://superuser.com/questions/104917/chrome-tab-ordering/1139391#1139391

Answer (score 0):

[Recent Tabs extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/recent-tabs/ocllfmhjhfmogablefmibmjcodggknml) is the best I think. You can use `ctrl+Q` or `ctrl+~` or assign your own shortcut key for it.