# Switching back to last *used* tab on Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

How do I toggle back to the last tab used in Chrome on Mac? Ctrl-Tab and Ctrl-Shift-Tab navigates the tabs in order.  But I want to switch back and forth between two tabs similar to how how Cmd-Tab switches between the last two apps.  There's [a way to do this on Firefox](https://superuser.com/questions/290704/switching-back-to-last-tab-on-firefox) but is there a solution for Chrome?

Comment: Also consider using either [Opera](http://www.opera.com/) or [Vivaldi](https://vivaldi.com/) which are both chromium-based browsers that support last used tab via ctrl-tab

Comment: Would you consider accepting http://superuser.com/a/1115469/170305 which is a direct solution that is current (didn't work when you posted the question)?

Alternately bounty it...

Comment: Click Ctrl + Tab

Comment: @djechlin: See my comment on your answer.

Comment: This is a known issue that Chrome does not value.  I switched to Opera solely for this issue and it's wonderful.  Here's the thread on the issue going back to 2009: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=5569  It's marked as "won't fix".  Do you really still want to use Chrome???

Comment: There is no direct way. There for I move the two tabs together - next to each other

Comment: Oh yeah, 23 answers (at the moment) to try to solve a simple task that must be provided by the product out-of-the-box from the day one. Google, WHY..?!

Comment: Lovely, so many people have the habit with me.

Comment: Shame on Google! Almost 10 year and no progress to enable ctrl+tab to switch between two last tabs directly by chrome or by extension.

Comment: I'm upset because this problem still not solved...

Comment: For those using Windows, [this extension](https://www.autocontrol.app/switch-to-last-used-tab-in-chrome) is the definitive solution to the problem.

Comment: There is now a no-extension solution with a native shortcut -- see https://superuser.com/a/1679002/197108 (it was ranked 19th with 1 upvote when I found it, so I thought I'd help the guy out)

Comment: Commenting to try to draw more attention to the [solution linked above](https://superuser.com/a/1679002) – this feature is now included natively as a consequence of the "Search Tabs" feature (Cmd+Shift+A). No need to resort to an extension!

Answer (score 117, accepted):

Chrome has no native keyboard shortcut for this, but there's an extension you can use:

[Recent Tabs (Chrome Web Store)](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ocllfmhjhfmogablefmibmjcodggknml)

#### Features

- You can specify any keyboard shortcut you like (default: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd>).
- You can configure it to

  - show a list of the most recent tabs (much like <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>).
  - toggle between the last 2 tabs.

  whenever you press the keyboard shortcut.

#### Screenshot [image: screenshot]

Comment: Any way this can override Ctrl+Tab?

Comment: Just using an extension, no. The extensions web store page says *You may ask why didn't I use Ctrl+Tab instead, that's cause Chrome does now allow extensions to map this shortcut key.* If you insist in this shortcut, you could assign a different key to it and do a remapping with AutoHotkey.

Comment: Thanks. +1 for AutoHotKey. Shame Chrome has us jumping through hoops for such basic functionality.

Comment: You can bind to Ctrl+Tab by manually editing the Preferences file.  Instructions here: http://superuser.com/questions/104917/chrome-tab-ordering/1139391#1139391

Comment: I could not get this extension to work. Take a look at Harshay Buradkar's answer below -- their extension worked for me: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/clut-cycle-last-used-tabs/cobieddmkhhnbeldhncnfcgcaccmehgn

Comment: This does not work with the latest update of Chrome.

Comment: On my Chrome 71 under Mint 19 system, it brings up a list of MRU tabs, but then I manually need to click the one it highlights. It wouldn't be so bad if I could just press Enter or something (I tried a few things), but the way it is now, I still waste time with the mouse, just to go back to the previous tab. I appreciate your work, but I wish this could be better.

Comment: The [AutoControl extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/autocontrol/lkaihdpfpifdlgoapbfocpmekbokmcfd) for Chrome can redefine native shortcuts like `Ctrl+Tab` and others. No need for sneaky hacks or manual edits.

Comment: by the way this feature works natively with Ctrl-Tab in Opera and Firefox

Comment: AutoControl does not support Mac! So it's a nope for me!

Comment: @Dr.X Thanks for pointing out that Opera does tabs right. My company doesn't allow Firefox but they're ok with Chromium based browsers.

Comment: Is not a solution for this problem.

Comment: I find it interesting that the default shortcut is Ctrl+Q, which in many Linux distributions is the default shortcut for closing the application. :D I still find it amazing that the people behind Chrome never decided to add such functionality. This is actually one of the main reasons why I try to stay away from Chrome(ium) - I use many, many tabs and switching between tabs in this web browser is a nightmare hence reduced productivity for me.

Comment: biggest missing shortcut ever...

Comment: With `Alt + C` defined as the RecentTab shortcut, I use: `#IfWinActive ahk_class Chrome_WidgetWin_1` (EOL) `^Tab::Send !{c}` (EOL) in my Autohotkey script.

Comment: As others pointed out, AutoControl was a game changer for me! See [this SE answer](https://superuser.com/a/1630773/327009).

Answer (score 132):

I really wanted this feature myself, I have tried most existing extensions already available but none of them worked properly.

I went ahead and tried my hand at developing one myself and it seems to be working for me.  **The project is now open source** on [GitHub](https://github.com/harshayburadkar/clut-chrome-extension).  Figured it might help others, too.

Here is the link: 
[CLUT: Cycle Last Used Tabs](http://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/clut-cycle-last-used-tabs/cobieddmkhhnbeldhncnfcgcaccmehgn)

Keys can be changed in keyboard shortcut settings on the Chrome extensions page:
[image]
[image]
[image]

Or, for older versions of Chrome:
[image]

Comment: I don't know how you did it better than everyone else, but I want to give you major props here and hope the whole world finds out about this extension. For many people, this is literally a dealbreaker that prevents them from switching to Chrome.

Comment: Also, for people who want to map this to Ctrl+Tab, the [Ctrl+Tab MRU plugin page](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ctrl%20tab-mru/ialfjajikhdldpgcfglgndennidgkhik?hl=en) has instructions for manually editing your preferences file (you don't need to install that plugin, you just need to follow their instructions). It really works!

Comment: be aware that this extension tracks your usage with Google Analytics https://github.com/harshayburadkar/clut-chrome-extension/blob/1d80bb7343a7e9e8dd2b3b566eb4e815bc39eb85/background.js#L340-L360

Comment: Harshay, could you comment on mark's comment? The tracking code is still present at master...

Comment: @BorislavIvanov Its usual Google Analytics which every website anyways already uses. It is to see how many people actually use the extension as opposed to install to try out but don't remove the extension even if it they don't like it. It is anonymous tracking and it just shows for e.g. 3000 users used it in the last week and so on. None of any private data is tracked. I added it to see how much is people's interest towards the extension and to decide if I should invest in improving the extension further. Mark's comment is just creating a little unnecessary scare.

Comment: @NeilTraft, The instructions for manually editing doesn't seem to work for me on Windows 10. I edit the file, but as soon as I restart Chrome, the file gets overwritten, and the default Ctrl+Tab behavior gets restored.

Comment: @devuxer Agreed, I find the same on all platforms: Linux, Mac. I have gotten into the habit of editing the Preferences file before every single time I start Chrome, since I'm so addicted to the functionality. This works okay for me since luckily I only restart Chrome once every couple weeks at most.

Comment: Now with Chrome version 75.0.3770.80, the shortcuts can be edited under chrome://extensions/shortcuts (or from the sandwich menu on the upper left, once on extensions)

Comment: @HarshayBuradkar I deleted my comment, you are right to defend your product against unnecessary scare. But I still believe there's something fundamentally wrong with secretly embedding a usage tracker in your product. I fully understand that in this case it is extremely benign, but even usage data is personal data and right now you are collecting it without user consent. Everyone who does this asks for it, so should you.

Comment: This a just a free open-source tool, not my 'product'. There is nothing to hide.

Can you elaborate on what personal data you think it is tracking which you are concerned about?

Comment: GDPR does not care if it's free, and I am sure you will find that it mentions the kind of data you are collecting.

Comment: @HarshayBuradkar I think all folks are asking for is a notification that you track analytics. It is a free open source tool, and it sounds like you're not doing anything dodgy with the information, but you should at least consider notifying people since you are collecting the information.

Comment: To use permanent "Ctrl+Tab" and "Ctrl+Shift+Tab" shortcuts (i.e. properly synced and kept between Chrome restarts) follow this clever answer: https://superuser.com/a/1326712/183908

Comment: Hi @HarshayBuradkar Thank you for this great extension. I'm too one of the guys that do not like the tracking part of it, although different from everyone that complained here I just forked your code and removed the tracking part of it. So if anyone want to give it a try it is available at my repo: https://github.com/jjcampos/clut-chrome-extension

Answer (score 128):

**Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.**

On Mac it is <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> then <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Uses Chrome's native tab history feature and does not require any extensions or registry hacks. When you hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> it will list your tabs with the last used highlighted ready for you to press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

This is pretty convenient fast once you have done it a few times to get used to it. Also means you can use that muscle memory on someone else's computer and all Chrome based browsers. You can also search the list by typing .

If you really must use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> then here is an [AHK](https://www.autohotkey.com/) script for you:

```
; Ctl+Tab in chrome to goto recent
#If WinActive("ahk_exe Chrome.exe")
    prevChromeTab()
    {
        send ^+a
        SetKeyDelay, 50
        send {BackSpace}
        send {Enter}
    }
    ^Tab::prevChromeTab()
    return
#If
```

Took a while for me to tune that SetKeyDelay to be as short as possible.

The additional backspace key is just a garbage key to trigger a response from the UI to speed up the animation. The result makes it so fast you can't see the UI popup. (normally there is a slow fade-in animation).

If it doesn't work for you try increasing the SetKeyDelay to allow the UI more time to appear.

Comment: Nothing happens for me when I press Ctrl+Shift+A. Is that feature still around?

Comment: yup, it sure is. If you are on Mac try command+shift+a. Otherwise, no idea why it's not working for you.

Comment: Thanks! This is IMO the best answer here. Usually i just need the last tab used to go back to. With this approach i can do it easily. command+shift+a than and enter, as the last one is already selected. You can also use down arrow to walk further in the history. No extension needed. Really helpful!

Comment: you can also search that list by typing  I should add that to my answer

Comment: As of Jan 2022 this is the best answer. Although I wish I didn't have to press enter having to lift my right hand with a builtin command

Comment: If your hand is on your mouse just click it. Might be faster. 

Comment: I'm very happy I scrolled down far enough to see this answer.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer @Sajee

Comment: Note that this will switch to the previous tab across all windows, whereas in browsers like Firefox (or extensions like PreviousTab) the last tab is maintained per-window. This may or may not be desirable depending on your preferred use-case

Comment: What is AHK? Where add the script?

Comment: AHK is a program called Auto Hot Key It basically lets you create any shortcut keys you want for any application and much more. I added a link to the website in my answer for you.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you so much. 
This is a huge help Press Ctrl+Shift+A

Comment: I like this since heavy user of cmd + shift + A to search tabs. I don't need to remember another key pattern :)

Comment: Ok it's something, but I still want this to be a _one key-press_. Like an old-school animator, I need to flip between two tabs quickly, 100's of reps, as I compare pixels between two tabs (e.g. tab 1: a website layout vs tab 2: a Figma concept).

Comment: @Kalnode try the ahk script then. Or you can always just break the figma tab off into another window and use alt+tab

Comment: CMD+Shift+A made it for me! I've been using Opera browser for 7 years just because of the recent tab feature. Also tried extensions - don't work well enough or in all contexts. The CMD+Shift+A (on mac) is the best solution so far. But I just can't understand why CTRL+TAB doesn't have this behaviour natively?! It's so strange.

Answer (score 27):

There's finally a Chrome extension that solves this for good.

It's called [**Tab Thumbnails Switcher**](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tab-thumbnails-switcher/jpaiaplhepeiilhiegfnknedhjepknng).

It supports <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> out of the box for switching between tabs in last used order.

[image]

From the extension's page:

> A tab switcher menu with thumbnail previews similar to Windows 10 task switcher.
>
> ➭   Tabs are in recently used order.
>
> ➭   You can use Ctrl+Tab and Ctrl+Shift+Tab to select the
>            desired tab or choose a different shortcut.
>
> ➭   Mouse-only method: Click on the toolbar button and then
>            click on the desired tab.
>
> ➭   It doesn't interfere with the web page you are viewing.
>
> ➭   The tabs menu pops up instantly for a fast tab switching.
>
> ➭   Works offline. No need for an internet connection.
>
> ➭   Tab Thumbnails Switcher does not access or collect your
>            personal data.
>   ...
>
> ✔ The tab menu is implemented in machine code, which allows it to pop up instantly without annoying loading delays.
>
> ✔ It can redefine Ctrl+Tab shortcut for switching between tabs.
>
> ✔ It doesn't inject code into every page you visit, thus avoiding sluggish page loads and conserving CPU and memory.
>
> ✔ It works on ALL tabs. Either PDF documents, the New Tab Page, extension pages, Chrome pages, you name it.

Comment: the problem is you have to install an exe file in your computer which I can't for security resons

Comment: @derloopkat, distrust by default should always be the norm. However, in this case the executable comes from the Chrome Web Store. There's no way Google is going to distribute malware. I myself was quite wary so I installed it on a VM and monitored its activity. Only then I came here and posted it.

Comment: This seems to be a derivative of another one called [AutoControl Shortcut Manager](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/autocontrol-shortcut-mana/lkaihdpfpifdlgoapbfocpmekbokmcfd?hl=en) which can do this too.

Comment: Here is how to do it without thumbnails: [Switch to last used tab in chrome](https://www.autocontrol.app/switch-to-last-used-tab-in-chrome#MRU-tabs)

Comment: This one doesn't work on macOS, but found a good one that does: http://tabappswitcher.com/

Answer (score 20):

I finally found a **REAL Ctrl-Tab solution** and not just an *"use an alternative keyboard shortcut"*-solution!

1. Install this extension: **[CLUT: Cycle Last Used Tabs](http://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/clut-cycle-last-used-tabs/cobieddmkhhnbeldhncnfcgcaccmehgn)**
2. Then go to **the chrome extensions** (**chrome://extensions** or newer Version: **chrome://extensions/shortcuts**) and scroll down to the Keyboard shortcuts
3. Enter a keyboard shortcut, e.g. **Ctrl+A** for "Quick switch"
4. Close Chrome completely
5. Open the Chrome preferences file:

   - Mac: **~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Preferences**
   - Windows: **C:\Users\YOUR_USERNAME\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Preferences**
   - Ubuntu: **~/.config/chromium/Default/Preferences**
6. Search for the previously set keyboard shortcut inside the file, e.g. **Ctrl+A** and replace it with **Ctrl+Tab**.
7. Save and close the file
8. Reopen Chrome and be finally a **happy** Chrome user!

Comment: This doesn't work for me on the latest version. Whenever I close Chrome and change Ctrl+A to Ctrl+Tab, and restart Chrome, the browser changes it back to Ctrl+A.

Comment: Are you sure, that Chrome is completely closed when you edit the preferences file?

Comment: For which OS is it not working?

Comment: @Sheen and @DarkCowboy, here is a simpler way to use `ctrl-tab` as a shortcut without editing the prefs file: https://superuser.com/a/1326712/736443 It sidesteps the checking Chrome does to block `ctrl-tab`, so it's Chrome itself that saves the shortcut to its prefs file. That means it will survive restarts of the app.

Comment: This worked for me, but, before closing Chrome, I had to copy all the contents of the `Preferences` file to clipboard. Had to do this because, somehow, when restoring my windows from the previous session, chrome was replacing the `Preferences` content with something else. So: copy `Preferences` content to clipboard, quit chrome, paste back the content from clipboard to `Preferences`, do the key replacement, save the file and start Chrome. Worked fine for me

Comment: Not working because when chrome exists it is reverted back. It seems that value is not only stored in Preferences file but also somewhere else when can be reverted.

Comment: This was written by the author of another comment above and was detailed there: https://superuser.com/a/762887/99916

Comment: Since I only have Chrome portable installed, then  Chrome\User Data\Default\Preferences as in %UserProfile%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Preferences does not exist, nor can I find any Preferences in the GoogleChromePortable folder.

However, for CLUT,  I was able to change the shortcut key to Alt+1 to  go to last accessed  tab by going to chrome://extensions/shortcuts, (which is not part of the extensions menu).

Answer (score 19):

Recent Tabs has a serious problem of interfering with keyboard events handling. It slows down the whole browser key handling. For example, after enabling the extension, go visit http://fullscreenmario.com and try to control Mario with keyboards. FPS goes rapidly down to 5 or 6.

Not a problem, but a limitation with the extension is it can't move between `chrome://*` pages or blank page.

There is a working alternative : [Toggle Switch Recent Last Tabs](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/toggle-switch-recent-last/odhjcgnlbagjllfbilicalpigimhdcll). It doesn't slow down the browser. It can switch between any pages.

Comment: Imho not any, but only between two. But it has useful option(only one option :) ) - go to recent on close. So it is very useful

Comment: The link is dead

Comment: @User which one,link to alternative is ok at the moment...

Comment: ```Toggle Switch Recent Last Tabs.``` works well, but seems to not be able to switch tabs across chrome windows.

Comment: You now have to pay $1 to use it.

Answer (score 11):

Vimium is really cool. i.e. ^ (Shift + 6) to switch to previous tab
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vimium/dbepggeogbaibhgnhhndojpepiihcmeb?hl=en

Comment: Pity it doesn't switch between the previous and current tab, so that you can use it to go back to the previous tab and then return to your current tab.

Comment: I wish Vimium add the support for cycling through the tab

Answer (score 8):

I created a minimalist Chrome extension called [**Previous Tab**](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/previous-tab/bjaniflnlhhofabpoamhnobeonjcjjpl?hl=en) ([PreviousTab.com](http://previoustab.com)) to solve this problem.  This extension requires no permissions at all.

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>q</kbd> to switch to the previously active tab, or click the Previous Tab icon.

You may customize the keyboard shortcut by visiting chrome://extensions/shortcuts

Note that <kbd>Tab</kbd> is [not a supported key](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/commands/#supported-keys) for Chrome extension commands.

Comment: This works great with the AHK trick mentioned above (something I couldn't get to work with Quick Tabs). To use Ctrl+Tab to toggle between two tabs, just install mark's Previous Tab, set the Keyboard shortcut to Alt+S under chrome://extensions/shortcuts 
then use an AHK script with the following: 
#IfWinActive ahk_class Chrome_WidgetWin_1
^Tab::Send !{s} 
#IfWinActive

Comment: This extension on it's own works great!

Answer (score 6):

I've found these to work for me:

- `Command + 1-8` will select the tab at that position,
- `Command + 9` will select the last tab.

If you are like me and have more than 9 tabs open, you are left with cycling through tabs with:

- `Command + {` to go back to a previous page
- `Command + }` to go forward to a page that you came from (after u click back)

Comment: `Command + 9` select the last (right-most) tab. The question is about selecting the last *used* (most recently-used tab), not the last tab on the right of the tab-bar.

Comment: This isn't helpful in making chrome act like every other subwindowed application

Comment: This is the least intrusive working answer (i.e. no need to install an extension)! For me that want to move back and forth between two tabs, I can order one to the rightmost position and reach it with `Ctrl+9` and use for example `Ctrl+5` to get the other page that I use.

Comment: This is correct and somewhat useful, but does not answer the question (which is about navigating to the last used tab, regardless of where it's positioned).

Answer (score 6):

If you have a full size keyboard, you can use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>PgUp</kbd> (go to prev tab) and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>PgDn</kbd> (go to next tab). It is not the same but close enough for me.

Comment: This works like a charm in Chrome 85! Thanks!

Comment: On Chrome 91, this goes to the left tab or right tab, but not the last used tab as the question requires.

Comment: This goes to the previous/next tabs in order, not to the last visited tab.

Comment: Yes, wrong answer but you can also go Ctrl+Tab or Ctrl+Shift+Tab which I find easier.

Answer (score 5):

**Update**: Building on [Shad's clever approach](https://superuser.com/a/1328062/736443) using AutoHotkey, here's how to enable <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>tab</kbd> to open the QuicKey recent tabs menu, navigate within it by pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>tab</kbd> again to select a tab, and then releasing <kbd>ctrl</kbd> to switch to that tab (**Windows only**):

- Install [QuicKey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/quickey-%E2%80%93-the-quick-tab-s/ldlghkoiihaelfnggonhjnfiabmaficg) from the Chrome webstore.
- Download and install [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/download/ahk-install.exe).
- Open your PC's startup folder by following [these instructions](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/FAQ.htm#Startup).
- Go to [this GitHub page](https://gist.github.com/fwextensions/511e0f6886eac3d07cf7a21fbb10a6c7) and click *Download ZIP*.
- Unzip the archive and drag the `ctrl-tab.ahk` file from the ZIP into your startup folder.
- Double-click the `ctrl-tab.ahk` file.

Now switch between a few different tabs in Chrome using the mouse (since QuicKey was just installed, it doesn't have any recent tab history). Then press and release <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>tab</kbd> to switch to the previous tab. If you press <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>tab</kbd> and keep holding <kbd>ctrl</kbd>, a menu of recent tabs will open. Press <kbd>tab</kbd> to select the next tab in the list. When the desired one is selected, release <kbd>ctrl</kbd> to switch to it.

The other shortcuts listed below continue to work, so you can press <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>Q</kbd> to open QuicKey and search for a tab.

---

[QuicKey (Chrome webstore)](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/quickey-%E2%80%93-the-quick-tab-s/ldlghkoiihaelfnggonhjnfiabmaficg) is another extension that provides this missing feature. It also offers a menu that's somewhat similar to the most recently used (MRU) menu you get in Firefox after pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>tab</kbd> and then releasing <kbd>tab</kbd> while holding down <kbd>ctrl</kbd>, which makes it easy to select any recent tab from the list.

- **To switch to the most recently used tab:**

  - Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> (<kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> on Windows).
- **To switch to the next most recently used tab:**

  - Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> again within 750ms. Press it repeatedly to navigate further back in history.
  - Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> to navigate in the opposite direction.
- **To pick a tab from the menu using just the keyboard:**

  - Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>Q</kbd> but keep holding the <kbd>ctrl</kbd> key (<kbd>alt</kbd> key on Windows).
  - Press <kbd>W</kbd> to move down through the list of recent tabs.
  - Press <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>W</kbd> to move up.
  - Release <kbd>ctrl</kbd> to switch to the selected tab.

[image]

The above keyboard shortcuts can be changed in `chrome://extensions/shortcuts`.

Answer (score 3):

Chrome on Windows (at least version 30) allows to use a `Ctrl+Tab` keyboard shortcut for the extensions, and some extensions do use this functionality.
  The following might work on Mac as well:

1. Install an extension which switches to last viewed tab, like
   [FLST Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/flst-chrome/ajnianifcggmdojhnmjichjmnjpplcha) (remembers only one tab into the past) or [Ctrl+Tab
   MRU](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ctrl%2Btab-mru/ialfjajikhdldpgcfglgndennidgkhik) (requires a bit longer `Ctrl+Tab` press).
2. Go to `chrome://extensions` page, click on 'Keyboard shortcuts' link at the very bottom and set `Ctrl+Tab` as keyboard shortcut for the extension you installed in *step 1*

Comment: Ctrl+Tab MRU is the closest option to what I'm used to in Opera and FF

Comment: How does Chrome support `Ctrl+Tab`? Whenever I try to set that as a shortcut for an extension in the extension tab, Chrome switches to the next tab. From the `Ctrl-Tab MRU`-Extension: _It seems that CHROME HAS DISABLED the possibility to use Ctrl+Tab as a shortcut :-( I'll be looking into this and if we get a workaround for this_

Answer (score 3):

Here is the AutoHotKey script to remap the Ctrl+Tab shortcut with [CLUT](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/clut-cycle-last-used-tabs/cobieddmkhhnbeldhncnfcgcaccmehgn) (from Harshay answer) only with Chrome:

```
; Chrome context
#IfWinActive ahk_class Chrome_WidgetWin_1
^Tab::Send !{w}
+^Tab::Send !{s}

; Back to global context
#IfWinActive
```

It does not emulate exactly the real Ctrl+Tab behavior: Ctrl+Tab will switch only between the two last tabs, and Ctrl+Shift+Tab will switch through the whole history.

Comment: [AutoHotKey](https://autohotkey.com/) is for Microsoft Windows.

Answer (score 3):

At least three chromium-based browsers now have tab cycling in MRU (Most Recently Used) order via <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd>:

- [Brave](https://brave.com)
- [Vivaldi](https://vivaldi.com/)
- [Opera](https://www.opera.com/)

All three allow using Chrome Extensions in the google chrome store.

Answer (score 3):

If you need to specifically work with 2 tabs, you can drag the tab out to create a new Chrome window.

Then you can <kbd>ALT</kbd> <kbd>Tab</kbd> on Windows and <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd> <kbd>`</kbd> on a Mac.

Answer (score 3):

The tricky solution to achieve this on Windows is to combine [Quick Tabs](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/quick-tabs/jnjfeinjfmenlddahdjdmgpbokiacbbb) chrome extensions and [AutoHotkey](https://autohotkey.com/) script. I've described it in details [here](https://github.com/boika/chrome-ctrl-tab), so here is in a nutshell:

1) Quick Tabs is an [open-source](https://github.com/babyman/quick-tabs-chrome-extension), customizable extension, that allows you redefine some CSS styles and allows to setup hotkey for switching MRU tabs. Also it supports keyboard navigation (move to next/previous tab). However chrome doesn't let you bind <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> as a keyboard shortcut, so you need to register another one (for example <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>) and then use AutoHotkey script to "remap" <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> for chrome into <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>.

2) I won't put here the AutoHotkey script, you can find it [here](https://github.com/boika/chrome-ctrl-tab/blob/master/chrome-ctrl%2Btab.ahk). It covers <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> remapping and handle all the keyboard navigation.

As a result you will see something like that when press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> in active chrome window:

[image]

Arrows navigation, <kbd>Esc</kbd>, both <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> are working the way you expected.

Comment: That's some serious AHK wizardry! You may want to check out my QuicKey extension: https://fwextensions.github.io/QuicKey/ It looks much like your styling of Quick Tabs without any custom CSS. And by slightly modifying your AHK script, I was able to get `ctrl-tab` working nicely with it: https://gist.github.com/fwextensions/511e0f6886eac3d07cf7a21fbb10a6c7 Quickly pressing `ctrl-tab` to toggle between tabs seems much faster and more reliable than when I was testing with Quick Tabs.

Comment: It's not that complicated, press ctrl-e to open the quicktab list and press enter to go to that last one which is the one that is selected by default, want the one before, just press down. Also, no need to keep holding down two keys to navigate bacwards

Comment: This is the one I used, and on Ubuntu, I didn't have to use AutoHotKey (or maybe that's no longer required anywhere now?)

Answer (score 3):

In contrast to a key combination for switching to the most recently used tab, you may like this [very light and intuitive solution](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tab-slider/nobaaibkcalggmjnjhnlmmcldllpogjp) for tabs organizing in the most recently used order, which is supported in all major browsers (Chrome, Firefox, Opera, other Chrome-based browsers): [Tab Slider](https://github.com/ZitRos/tab-slider#tab-slider). Its features are:

- Works just like Alt+Tab on Windows or Cmd+Tab on Mac, but with browser tabs
- Visually sorts tabs so you always see them in the MRU order (Ctrl+Tab switches to the next MRU tab)
- Works with pinned tabs as well
- Is customizable (however, I would advise sticking with defaults)

Try it! Hope you'll love it.

[image: img]

Comment: I've used this for years and am really surprised it is not more well-known. This gives almost exactly the behavior this question is asking about without having to do anything with key bindings or learning new keyboard shortcuts.  You can take it to the next level by adding Tab Wrangler to automatically close tabs you haven't touched in a while, and then tab management is almost completely automated. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tab-wrangler/egnjhciaieeiiohknchakcodbpgjnchh

Comment: @MarkMeuer TabSlider has a setting for keeping max N tabs on the screen (see extension settings by clicking on it). The way it works with sorting makes it close the oldest tabs - thus no tab-wrangler needed!

Comment: Thanks, I did not know that feature. That would also do a great job of keeping the number of tabs under control.  There is a subtle difference, however, that keeps me with Tab Wrangler.  Sometimes when researching something I might want to open a LOT of tabs and keep them there while I'm working. If I had a set maximum number of tabs to be open then some of them would drop off too soon. With a time-based approach to closing old tabs I can open a ton of them, work for a while, and then ignore them and they'll eventually close on their own.

Answer (score 2):

I built this Chrome extension to do just that; Toggle between the last two active tabs using a global hotkey. This means you don't need Chrome to be focused to toggle.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/toggletab/iblgdmlpmokbijhiebnffnffablkkedk

Answer (score 1):

I like to toggle between two tabs when filling out forms or comparing pages, etc. As a work around to there being no hot hey for the last used tab, I drag the two tabs into their own window and use the Command+Option+right arrow to go back and forth quickly.

Answer (score 1):

Ctrl + 1 takes you to tab 1

Ctrl + 2 takes you to tab 2 
etc..

Pretty handy if you're opening multiple links from a page that doesn't support middle clicking or right click menus.

Comment: That's nice, but doesn't answer the question of how to switch to the *last-used* tab. If you know, please edit your answer with the "edit" link.

Comment: i have 100500 tabs...

Answer (score 0):

- Install [quick tabs](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/quick-tabs/jnjfeinjfmenlddahdjdmgpbokiacbbb)
- Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd> (or <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd>)

  - A list of tabs shows up, that last one is already focused
- Hit <kbd>enter</kbd>

If you want to go through your history, press the down arrow once to the to the tab used before the last one.

I know there's an [answer using quick tabs already](https://superuser.com/a/1328062/44673) but it requires too much just to do it using ctrl-tab. I'd rather keep that functionality, plus, I often want to search my tabs, which is what the plugin is really designed for.

Answer (score 0):

The one I use if [Alt + Q](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/alt-%2B-q-switch-recent-act/odhjcgnlbagjllfbilicalpigimhdcll/related?hl=en). It costs $1; but it just works and doesn't require any configuration.

Answer (score -2):

There is official support for this command. Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>9</kbd>.
Please see the [this link](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/157179?hl=en).

Or am I missing something here?

Comment: The original question meant "last" as in "most recent in time; latest." not, "coming after all others in time or order; final." Ctrl+9 does the latter

Answer (score -2):

Looks like this is standard now on Chrome - when you close a tab, the focus jumps back to the last used tab. Just noticed it this week. Version 73.0.3683.86.

Comment: If this question was not 7 years ago, or if you provived with a link to the changelog, this answer might be helpful. But this way, it is not.

Comment: The question is about navigating to the most recently used tab _without_ closing the current tab.

Answer (score -3):

For me Ctrl+1 switches between two most recent tabs.