# Tab sequence in Chrome when using Ctrl+Tab

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts, browser-tabs, tabs

When I use tabs in Chrome I want to switch back and forth between the latest use tabs.

The Internet Explorer Tab sequence was adjustable to use the "latest use" sequence.

So pressing Ctrl+Tab releasing the Ctrl key and pressing it again, returns me to the previous page. So Ctrl+Tab moves me always back in the sequence of the latest used tabs.

The advantage is obvious. I opened a new tab from the current page. And I just want to get back to the previous page. If I already opened 2 other tabs from this page. I have to press Shift+Ctrl+Tab 3 times to get back to the previous page.

I couldn't find any addin that brings me back this feature. Or is there any other trick or keyboard sequence to achieve this?

**EDIT**: The question was closed, but the provided link doesn't answer my question. I don't want a new hotkey. I want to cycle back in the latest used sequence with the existing keystroke. Most of the addins in the links provide an additional UI.

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate because the question asks for the specific keyboard shortcut Ctrl+Tab whereas the other question asks for the functionality in general. Check out my answer in the other question, which exactly solves the problem for Ctrl+Tab: https://superuser.com/a/1258647/173260