# Switch to last used tab in macOS Terminal

Tags: macos, terminal

One of my favourite Firefox features is that Ctrl-Tab takes me to the last tab I *used*, not the next one in the line.

[Here](https://superuser.com/questions/402095/switching-back-to-last-used-tab-on-chrome) is a post requesting something similar for Chrome.

Is there any way, no matter how hacky, to apply this on Terminal?