# How do I change ctrl+tab cycling behaviour in MS Edge?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-edge

In Firefox, when I press Ctrl+Tab, it takes me through the tabs in recently used order. (I have 'Ctrl+Tab cycles through tabs in recently used order' enabled.)
In MS Edge, it takes me to the next tab to the right.

Cycling in recently used order lets me flip back and forth between my two most recent tabs without having to worry about whether I need to also hold down the Shift key.

Is there a similar setting as in Firefox to allow cycling in recently used order, or are we stuck with this deplorable behaviour?

Comment: Ctrl+Tab always goes to the next tab in all the browsers you mentioned. Why is it different on your computer?

Comment: Ok, maybe Chrome does, but Firefox has a setting, Ctrl+Tab cycles through tabs in recently used order, which I have enabled. I like it that way, because it lets me flip back and forth between my two most recently used tabs without having to worry whether I need to also hold down the Shift key.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Switching back to last \*used\* tab on Chrome](https://superuser.com/questions/402095/switching-back-to-last-used-tab-on-chrome)